# How i can configurate Msmtp to work with gmail SMTP

Tags: php, linux, email, debian, msmtp

I try to install on a server a msmtp whiwh work with Gmail SMTP.

My .msmtprc file :

```
defaults
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
account default
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
auth on
user thetranslationtrustee@linguacustodia.com
password XXXXXX
from thetranslationtrustee@linguacustodia.com
logfile /var/log/msmtp.log
```

My php.ini file have this line :

```
sendmail_path = /usr/bin/msmtp  -C /root/.msmtprc -t
```

the command :

```
msmtp arnaud.gicquel@linguacustodia.com
test
test
test
test
```

work perfectly and send a mail

but

```
>cat test_mail.php
 <?php
        if ( mail ( 'arnaud.gicquel@linguacustodia.com', 'Test mail from localhost', 'Working Fine.' ) ){
        echo 'Mail sent ';
        }

        else{
        echo 'Error. Please check error log.';
        }

?>
>php test_mail.php
Mail sent
```

seems to work but i never receive the mail

Anyone can help me to configure Msmtp to use Gmail as SMTP relay please

Comment: I don't see why emails from `linguacustodia.com` would be handled by gmail smtp, I am missing something obvious?

Comment: linguacustodia is our pro gmail account, it's google app's

Answer (score 1):

I have fix the problem. It was that /root/.msmtprc was with non-accesible right which have to be 600 and the owner www-data

Answer (score 1):

I type

sendmail_path = /usr/bin/msmtp -t

(witout Parameter -C)

into the php.ini file.

Then

```
mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)
```

works.